# Margin issue in webkit

Tags: html, css

I was having a simple brush with my HTML/CSS skills.

The code goes like this

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title> Margin Problem </title>
    <link href="doubt1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "page-header">
                Example Header 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE :

```
h1
{
    color:#FFFFFF ;
}
.page-header
{
    background:#9C27B0;
}
```

When I run it in chrome my text "Example Header" came after some white space lines from top of page, when i did inspect element the chrome webkit by defaults sets margin to 8px can i find a way to decrease it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS Reset. The simplest is:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Example without CSS Reset: http://jsfiddle.net/7c4hawr5/1/

Example with CSS Reset: http://jsfiddle.net/7c4hawr5/

You can find more extensive CSS Resets here: http://www.cssreset.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a default margin value for the body tag on all browsers (not only on webkit), to reset that simply use:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the `body` `margin` to `0` like the below example:

```css
h1
{
    color:#FFFFFF ;
}
.page-header
{
    background:#9C27B0;
}
body {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "page-header">
    Example Header 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some useful rules for CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    /* Optional, leaves zero whitespace when using display: inline-block; */
    font-size: 0px;
}
```